# No data for [ruby-on-rails] on "Compare number of Questions per week, for 3 given tags, over a specified period"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer

In [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201968/compare-number-of-questions-per-week-for-3-given-tags-over-a-specified-period?tag0=python&tag1=php&tag2=java#graph), I am trying to compare 3 tags to see the number of Questions asked for each per week, but [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) fails to appear:

```
DECLARE @tag0 nvarchar(10) = ##tag0:string?python##
DECLARE @tag1 nvarchar(10) = ##tag1:string?php##
DECLARE @tag2 nvarchar(10) = ##tag2:string?java##
DECLARE @weeks int         = ##weeks:int?52##

SELECT
  dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, q.CreationDate), 0) week,
  TagName,
  count(*)
FROM PostTags pt
JOIN Posts q ON q.Id=pt.PostId
JOIN Tags t ON t.Id=pt.TagId
WHERE
  TagName IN (@tag0, @tag1, @tag2) AND
  q.CreationDate < dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0) AND
  q.creationdate between Dateadd(ww, -@weeks, getdate()) AND getdate()
GROUP BY dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, q.CreationDate), 0), TagName
ORDER BY dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, q.CreationDate), 0)
```

The graph:

[image]

As a bonus, are there ways to improve that query (it is a modified version [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260570/how-to-compare-tags-by-question-count-over-time/260571#260571)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tagname is defined in the schema as `nvarchar(25)`.

Your parameters are defined as `nvarchar(10)`.

`ruby-on-rails` happen to be longer than 10 chars but only the first 10 are stored in tag0. So you are only selecting tags with the name `ruby-on-ra`.

This [forked query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202612/compare-number-of-questions-per-week-for-3-given-tags-over-a-specified-period?tag0=ruby-on-rails&tag1=django&tag2=python-3.x&weeks=52#graph) does work.

I changed this line:

```
DECLARE @tag0 nvarchar(25) = ##tag0:string?ruby-on-rails##
```